# How to get the bottom border to stretch fully across a page in CSS

Tags: css

I have a bottom border of:

```
div#footer-case{
border-top:solid black 1px;
    width:100%;
margin:8% auto;
      }
```

but the border does not span the whole page, instead there are about 5px on the left and the right.

i set the width to 100%, but i do not know why it will not fully go left to right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to edit the default browser margin of the body, try this:

```
div#footer-case
{
   border-top:solid black 1px;
   width:103%;
   margin-left:-10px;
}
```

Tested with FF 8, Chrome 16, and Safari 5 on OS X Lion.

Comment: It the user chooses the right screen resolution, this will work fine.

Comment: Yep.  In my test cases it worked in everything from 400x200 to 2500x1200.  That would be the complete range on my 27" iMac.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

Browsers have default margin on the viewport, usually set in modern browsers on the body element. Try resetting it with this:

```
body {margin:0;padding:0;}
```

It may help in ongoing development efforts to implement a nice CSS reset such as this one:

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Or even just studying default user agent stylesheets and how resets work would help understand all the fun little challenges we have to confront to get CSS to bend to our wills and behave consistently. Here's a nice article on the subject:

http://meiert.com/en/blog/20070922/user-agent-style-sheets/

Comment: Please familiarize yourself with how to properly post code here.  I've fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

```
body {
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

.footer
{ height:125px; width:103; position:relative; background-color:#333; color:#FFF; margin-left:-10px;}